# Unity 3D - rotating gameobject without rotating axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

Hope my title summarises my problem. I have a rocket on a 2d game that only moves horizontally across the screen. I want it to rotate towards the players finger (the direction of movement), but cannot find a way to rotate the object without rotating the whole axis it moves on. I simply need it to seem like it has turned, but it should keep moving along the x. How can I go about this?

```
void Start () {
    //scoreT = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI> ();
    gameSpeed = 1;
    score = 0;
    Rigidbody2D rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float MoveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    Vector2 Movement = new Vector2 (MoveHorizontal, 0.0f);

    rb2d.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0, 0f, rb2d.velocity.x * -tilt);
    transform.Translate (MoveHorizontal * speed, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to modify `rigidbody.rotation` of your rocket rocket to make it tilt, when it moves, to one direction or to another. For example:

```
float tilt - 0.3f;
//In case you prefer the rotation in another axis you just need to modify the position of the rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt
rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
```

Since you didn't add any code I am not sure how you are moving your rocket, so I will post a generic code you will need to adapt depending on your own project:

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    //The tild factor
    public float tilt;
    //The limit within the spaceship can move
    public Boundary boundary;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        //You will need to capture the screen touchs of the user for the inputs
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        //Applying the movement to the GameObject
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

        //To ensure the GameObject doesnt move outside of the game boundary
        rigidbody.position = new Vector3 
        (
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 
            0.0f, 
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
        );

        //Here is where you apply the rotation 
        rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }
}
```

As an aside, you are doing a space 2D game you may be interested in checking this tutorial:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/space-shooter-tutorial

Comment: I seem to be getting an error saying 'UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for rotation. Any idea what I've done wrong? Thank you

Comment: @Mattattack I think the problem is the Quaternion.Euler I posted is expecting a rigidbody, not a rigidbody2D... Try to add a rigidbody (not a 2D) to the gameobject, and then you can  access that rigidbody component directly as in my code. That is, remove this: Rigidbody2D rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> (); As far as I know the script will access directly the rigidbody component of the GameObject which it's attached to

Comment: I had added the rigidbody2D trying to get it to work. Without the rigidbody2D it still does not work. When I begin to type rigidbody, the auto complete has a line through it, it is not recognized.

Comment: @Mattattack But you should add the rigidbody as a component of the GameObject from the editor first, then you can access it from code. Can you list what are the components in the rocket GameObject? You can see them from the editor

Comment: It has a rigidbody2D, boxcollider2D and circle collider2D

Comment: @Mattattack Change all those in the editor for the 3D version, that is rigidbody... Just keep in mind in Unity all games are in 3D, even if you are giving to the game a 2D perspective, so you can use the 3D rigidbody, colliders...

Comment: Yeah that seems the best solution. Out of interest, why does the engine present so many 2D options when they are so limited?

Comment: @Mattattack I am not sure why... Please, in case my answer solved your problem, accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to move your object in global/world space. As it seems the movement of your rocket is currently happening within local space. So when you rotate the rocket it's local coordinates are rotated as well. The world space coordinates are fixed and will never rotate when you change your rocket.
[Here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/31169/explanation-local-vs-global-space.html) is another explanation at that.

You can also have a look at [Transform.localPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) and [Transform.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) and see how your rocket behaves when using one or the other.

Comment: I've already tried setting my axis relative to the world and it seemed to have no effect, I may have done something wrong, but it still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the sprite/renderer a child of the GameObject that is your rocket.
Then you can freely rotate the sprite/renderer around without changing the rotation you move the parent GameObject.

This is a hacky solution but it achieves the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You must move your object relative to the world and rotate locally. 
So use Transform.position to move your object and Transform.LocalRotation to rotate it.

Or you can put the part that must rotate as a children of the object that translate, and rotate the children.

Comment: Can you explain how I can achieve this? I am failing to understand localRotation's properties.

Comment: you use Transform.LocalRotation has you use Transform.Rotation. 

The difference betwwen those two when you use Rotation it's de rotation of the object relative to the world
When you use Local rotation it's relative to his parent.