# Collider.isTouching for 3D colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

```
if (colliderBox.isTouching (col) && col.CompareTag("barrier")) {
        score++;
        this.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = col.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color;
    }

    if (spriteBox.IsTouching(col) && col.CompareTag("barrier") ) {
        Debug.Log (col);
        Debug.Log (colliderBox);
        SceneManager.LoadScene (mainMenu);
    }
```

Currently in my code, I was using a onTriggerEnter, to detect a collision with an object called 'barrier', but I have had to replace my 2d spriteBox and 2d colliderBox with 3D objects, and now isTouching is not a property of 3D colliders. I can not find a simple replacement. What can I replace them with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent version of the `isTouching`  function for 3D collision but you can roll your own. When `OnTriggerEnter`, store both colliders involved in a collection. When `OnTriggerExit` is called, check for both colliders involved and if already exit in the collection, remove them from the collection. This is what I am doing in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50415096/3785314) post with the `CollisionDetection` script.

Attach the `CollisionDetection` script to the objects that will be colliding.

To check if `Collider` is touching another `Collider`, change:

```
if (colliderBox.isTouching (col) && col.CompareTag("barrier")) { }
```

to:

```
if (CollisionDetection.IsTouching (colliderBox.gameObject, col.gameObject) && col.CompareTag("barrier")) {  }
```

---

You can also add ExtensionMethod for the CollisionDetection class:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool IsTouching(this Collider collider, Collider otherCollider)
    {
        return CollisionDetection.IsTouching(collider.gameObject, otherCollider.gameObject);
    }

    public static bool IsTouching(this GameObject collider, GameObject otherCollider)
    {
        return CollisionDetection.IsTouching(collider, otherCollider);
    }
}
```

Now, your `if (colliderBox.isTouching (col) && col.CompareTag("barrier"))` code should work without changes assuming that `colliderBox` is a type of `Collider` or `GameObject`.

Comment: I'm going to have a go with this, thanks! Is it recommended to use 3D colliders on 2D games? I have found some people saying to always use 3D colliders, however for my game it is easier to use 2D ones, but it seems to prohibit me from rotating the way I want (with rigidbody.rotation) to and access all the rigidbody features? Any advice?

Comment: No. Use 2D colliders with Sprites/SpriteRenderer. Use 3D colliders for models/MeshRenders. The-something applies to Rigidbody. It must match. I really can't suggest anything more than this until I see the type of game you're making

Comment: Would you mind looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408424/unity-3d-rotating-gameobject-without-rotating-axis/53412068?noredirect=1#comment93778924_53412068) for more reference? It explains my original problem. Thank you

Comment: That doesn't help. Is your character images or 3d model? A screenshot might also help

Comment: The image is 2D, it is an endless game where you simple move left and right to avoid objects.

Comment: sound s like it should be a 2D game. In your *future* questions, if you're gonna ask questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53408424/3785314) one, make sure to include a screenshot of what you're talking about. Without that, you may not get the proper solution. If you can't show the original images in your game due to privacy reasons, simply replace them a square or circle images. People just need to understand what you're doing to answer that kind of question

Answer (score 3):

After a long struggle with a problem in the OnTriggerEnter method I found another way

> collider1.bounds.Intersects(collider2.bounds)

although there is a special case where this method wont work , if collider2 is a hollow mesh collider like a box and collider1 is inside it , even if they are not touching it will return true for their intersection , so i advice using simple colliders like box and sphere colliders

Comment: bounds is essentially equivalent to a box collider, so take care when using this with any other colliders.

Comment: While not perfect, this is very close to what I'm frequently looking for (and this solution is annoyingly hard to find googling).